# Regular Expression to get attributes from HTML comment like string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a strings which could looks like:

1. `<!--Tag:Name-->`
2. `<!--Tag:Name param="abc"-->`
3. `<!--Tag:Name param="abc" param2="xyz"-->`

Additionally i have file with many of this tags so i want to first find all tags and then parse each one by one

example file

```
<head>
   <!--Tag:Test-->
   <!--Tag:Test2 param="abc"-->
   <!--Tag:Test3 param2="abc" param5="xyz"-->
</head>
```

I'm looking for Regex to parse this kind of scripts and in match get Name and attributes

I've tried something like

```
tempRegex = new RegExp(/<!--Tag:(.*?)\s{1,}(.*?=".*?")-->/, 'i');

`<!--Tag:Test param="abc" param2="xyz"-->`.match(tempRegex);
```

But it returns matching groups:

```
0: "<!--Tag:Test param="abc" param2="xyz"-->"
1: "Test"
2: "param="abc" param2="xyz""
```

What i want to achieve is

```
0: "<!--Tag:Test param="abc" param2="xyz"-->"
1: "Test"
2: param="abc" 
3: param2="xyz"
```

Comment: You've stated what it does.  Not what the problem is.

Comment: Also is there a reason this has to be a comment?  `<template tag="Name" param="abc" param2="xyz"></template>` would be much easier to process with existing native logic

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to extract to a 'key - value' thing ?

```
((\w+)[:=]"*(\w+)"*)
```

It would be:

```
Tag:Test
param="abc"
param2="xyz"
```

Comment: Yes, i want to extract to array looks like [TagName, first pair, second pair, etc]

Comment: This would fail for something like `<!--Tag:Name param="a:bc"-->`

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
/Tag:[a-z]+|[a-z\d]+="[^"]+"/gmi
```

https://regex101.com/r/6dVJXO/1

```js
var s = `<!--Tag:Name param="abc" param2="xyz"-->`;
var r = /Tag:[a-z]+|[a-z\d]+="[^"]+"/gmi;
console.log([...s.matchAll(r)]);
```

Comment: looks nice but it also match to `<Tag:Name param="abc" param2="xyz">` additionally i would preffer not global regex if possible because first i need get all this matching tags from file and then parse each one by one

Comment: @goq123 I see you've updated your question to reveal new requirements so step one would be to run `/<!--.[\s\S]*?-->/g` (https://regex101.com/r/vhl4Ln/1) against the whole string, loop the matches, and run the regex I've supplied in the answer against each match.

Comment: @goq123 Also, your question indicated that you can comment blocks so what's up with `<Tag:Name param="abc" param2="xyz">`??

Comment: i have strict rule that i match only `<!--Tag:name-->` with or without params i'm interested only in this shape of signature

Comment: @goq123 For future reference, make your question as complete as possible. You can easily combine everything I've shown you into something that works for you.

Comment: thank you for your help, i think question was complete and i added additional requirements when i saw replies, first i've added it to another response but it was deleted.

Comment: @goq123 "i added additional requirements when i saw replies" is precisely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the source code at https://github.com/artdecocode/rexml it kind of does what you want but you need to know the name of tags in advanced but you can change regex.

```js
/**
 * Extract member elements from an XML string. Numbers and booleans will be parsed into their JS types.
 * @param {string|!Array<string>} tag Which tag to extract, e.g., `div`. Can also pass an array of tags, in which case the name of the tag will also be returned.
 * @param {string} string The XML string.
 * @example
 *
 * const xml = `
 * <html>
 *   <div id="1" class="test" contenteditable>
 *     Hello World
 *   </div>
 * </html>
 * `
 * const [{ content, props }] = extractTag('div', xml)
 * // content: Hello World
 * // props: { id: 1, class: 'test', contenteditable: true }
 */
const extractTags = (tag, string) => {
  const tags = Array.isArray(tag) ? tag : [tag]
  const t = tags.join('|')
  const end1 = /\s*\/>/
  const end2 = />([\s\S]+?)?<\/\1>/
  const re = new RegExp(`<(${t})${simple.source}?(?:${end1.source}|${end2.source})`, 'g')

  const matches = mismatch(re, string, ['t', 'a', 'v', 'v1', 'v2', 'c'])
  const res = matches.map(({ 't': tagName, 'a': attributes = '', 'c': content = '' }) => {
    const attrs = attributes.replace(/\/$/, '').trim()
    const props = extractProps(attrs)
    return { content, props, tag: tagName }
  })
  return res
}
```